# How to recover a deleted branch in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I deleted a branch in TFS and just found out that I need the changes that were on it.

How do I recover the branch or the changes done on it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Specifically in Visual Studio go to "Tools-Options" then Select "Source Control-visual Studio Team Founation Server" and check the "Show deleted items in the Source Control explorer".

Having done that - you can then right click a folder and say "Undelete"

Answer (score 6):

As described in the [TFS FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/articles/tfsfaq.aspx):

**Are Deletes physical or logical? Can accidental deletes be recovered?**

Deletes are fully recoverable with the “undelete” operation. You wouldn’t want to do a SQL restore because that would roll back every change to the TFS in the time since the file was deleted.